# Let $E/F$ be a finite field extension of number field $F$. Can one complete integral basis of $F/Q$ to integral basis of $E/Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $E/F$ be a finite field extension of number field $F$.

$\textbf{Q:}$Can one complete integral basis of $F/Q$ to integral basis of $E/Q$? I doubt this works. Maybe one wants $E$ as a composite field of $F$ with another field $F'$ s.t. they have coprime discriminant. In general, I doubt it is true.

The reason to ask this question is that $V_1\subset V$ is a $R-$vector space. $Q$ is basically taking analogy of the following statement.

$\textbf{Q'1.}$ If I have a lattice $L\subset V$ and consider $L$'s image under $\frac{V}{V_1}$, does the image remain to be a lattice? I encountered the statement for $L$ lattice admitting Riemann form $E$(in other words, torus $\frac{V}{L}$ admits a non-trivial meromorphic section.) and this very riemann form gives the sense of discreteness of the image of lattice under the quotient.(i.e. Image of $L$ is a discrete lattice in the quotient.)

$\textbf{Q'2.}$ Is this lattice discrete without notion of riemann form? It seems that I want to drop the condition of existence of Riemann form here.

Comment: Are you asking whether a free $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $O_F$ can be extended to a free basis of $O_E$? This is true and easy.

Comment: @Mohan I can complete $Q$ basis for sure. However, taking integral basis does not guarantee that it generates $O_E$.

Comment: @Mohan For coprime discriminant case, it is clear one can extend but requires $E$ being composite of number fields with coprime discriminants.

Comment: What is the answer to my question? Is what I say is what you want? If it is something else, I won't try.

Comment: @Mohan Yes. This would explain the first question I asked. I do not see why $O_F$ $Z-$basis can be extended to $O_E$ basis in general. In particular $Z^r\to Z^s$ is embedding of abelian groups, then the image can be extended to a set of $Z-$basis.(i.e. It would generate the whole $Z^s$. Am I going to use something else here?) It may happen that $Z\to Z$ is multiplication by $2$. And the image does not hit the basis element. That is what I thought it does not hold in general.

Comment: $O_E/O_F$ is a finitely generated torsion free abelian group and thus free. Lift a basis to $O_E$ to do what you want.

Comment: @Mohan I see. Thanks a lot.